# .htaccess not redirecting as it should

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I modified a few rewrite rules of my .htaccess file today as follows:

From

```
RewriteRule ^about-us.php(.*)$ /about$1 [R=302,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^contact-us.php(.*)$ /service$1 [R=302,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^countertop-electrics/blenders(.*)$ /beverages/blenders [R=302,NC,L]
```

To

```
RewriteRule ^about-us.php(.*)$ /about [R=302,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^contact-us.php(.*)$ /service [R=302,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^countertop-electrics/blenders(.*)$ /beverages/blenders [R=302,NC,L]
```

The goal was to redirect a product page such as "countertop-electrics/blenders/product1234.html" to a simple category page such as "beverages/blenders" due to a change in how products and categories are sorted. I did this by dropping the $1 or $ but now it seems none of the RewriteRules are working. How else might I accomplish this? Thank you.

Comment: What you have looks fine

Comment: Why did you change the "about" and "service" rewrites?

Comment: I was under the assumption that the $1 is the "wildcard" or "variable" that is place after the redirected URL (e.g. contact-us.php?1234 would redirect to /services?1234 - correct? Are am I way off?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.+` in your regex:

```
RewriteRule ^about-us\.php.*$ /about [R=302,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^contact-us\.php.*$ /service [R=302,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^countertop-electrics/blenders.+$ /beverages/blenders [R=302,NC,L]
```

`QUERY_STRING` will be carried over to the new URI.

Comment: Do you see any reason why the first and second lines wouldn't be working?

Comment: Unless there are other conflicting rules those 2 lines should work fine.